# Changing color of a div on ng-click and resetting rest all to their normal colors

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I am trying to change the color of a div on click of `ng-click`. I have done half of the work.  I am able to toggle the color of the div when clicked, but I need all other divs to revert to their original color.  There should be no more than one div that is not its original color.

HTML code-

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    Hello, {{name}}!
    <div ng-init="item.isyellow = false" ng-repeat="item in realName" 
         ng-class="{yellow : item.isyellow}"  ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'" 
         ng-click="item.isyellow =!item.isyellow"  style="cursor:pointer">
        {{item.id}}
        {{item.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS-

```
.odd{
    background-color:white;  
}
.even{  
     background-color:grey;
}
.yellow{
     background-color:yellow;
}
```

Js-

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.realName=[{"id":1,"name":"A"},{"id":2,"name":"B"},{"id":3,"name":"c"},{"id":4,"name":"D"},{"id":5,"name":"E"},{"id":6,"name":"F"}];   
}
```

[Demo on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rhul/HB7LU/17479/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use, the ng repeat varaible $index, and use it, to, choose the row.

Check this working : [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/moncef_hbey/HB7LU/17481/)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.realName=[{"id":1,"name":"A"},{"id":2,"name":"B"},    {"id":3,"name":"c"},{"id":4,"name":"D"},{"id":5,"name":"E"},{"id":6,"name":"F"}];

    $scope.colorRow = function(index){
        $scope.row = index;
    }    

}
```

HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!

    <div ng-init="item.isyellow = false" ng-repeat="item in realName" ng-class="{yellow : $index == row}"  ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'" ng-click="colorRow($index)"  style="cursor:pointer"  >
        {{item.id}}
        {{item.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a working fiddle here. Basically, you just need your ng-click to run a function that toggles the color for the item that was selected, and then unselects all other items. If you don't want to add the "select" field like I did to your data, you could do this by passing in the $index value from the ng-repeat.

http://jsfiddle.net/stephen_hartzell/h72ej0rL/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!

    <div ng-repeat="item in realName" ng-class="{yellow : item.selected}"  ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'" ng-click="selectItem(item)"  style="cursor:pointer" >
    {{item.id}}
    {{item.name}}
</div>
```

The JavaScript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.realName=[{"id":1,"name":"A","selected":false},    {"id":2,"name":"B","selected":false},{"id":3,"name":"c","selected":false},{"id":4,"name":"D","selected":false},{"id":5,"name":"E","selected":false},{"id":6,"name":"F","selected":false}];


$scope.selectItem = function(selectedItem){
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.realName.length; i++){
        var item = $scope.realName[i];
        if(item.id == selectedItem.id){
            item.selected = !item.selected;
        }else {
            item.selected = false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two approaches:

#### Approach 1

Change your `ng-click` to call a function that loops through your array of `realName` and manually resets all the other objects.  This is not the most efficient approach, but it won't require much refactoring.

```
<div ng-init="item.isyellow = false" ng-repeat="item in realName" 
     ng-click="toggleItemAndResetOthers(item)">
    {{item.id}}
    {{item.name}}
</div>
```

Javascript function

```
$scope.toggleItemAndResetOthers = function (item ) {
    $scope.realName.forEach(function (name) {
        if (name == item)
            name.isyellow = !name.isyellow;
        else
            name.isyellow = false;
    });
}
```

#### Approach 2

It sounds like you're really more interested in highlighting a selected object.  So instead of manually updating each object, you could instead assign to a separate object called `selectedObject` and just have your `ng-class` check whether the `item == selectedObject`.  This changes how you treat the objects in your array, so it might not fit the rest of your existing code.  But based on what you are asking, I think this is a cleaner approach.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in realName" 
     ng-class="{yellow : item == selectedObject}" 
     ng-click="selectItem(item)">
    {{item.id}}
    {{item.name}}
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$scope.selectedObject = {};

$scope.selectItem = function (item) {
    if ($scope.selectedObject == item) //reference equality should be sufficient
        $scope.selectedObject = {}; //de-select if the same object was re-clicked
    else
        $scope.selectedObject = item;
};
```

See the [forked demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d85whemn/1/) for this approach.